# How would you go about recreating this chair in Sketchup?

Tags: 3d, sketchup

I'm going to try to recreate [this](https://www.montel.nl/003736003505000/montel-ray.html) chair in Sketchup, but am still a bit in doubt on how to approach it. Since the website has quite clear front, side and 45° photos, I could imagine just making a cube and apply the photos as texture to two sides (and creating a 45° face alongside with it), but I don't think it will completely work out.

I could also think of creating three Match Photo-cameras, but I don't think I could get them to match up perfectly, and would still struggle to trace it correctly.

How would you guys approach this, should I rather use some plugin, or what would you do?